# Wireguard + FIOS - no internet access

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, wireguard

After a few reboots my home setup of Wireguard stopped accessing internet. I can do handshake from outside the network and I can access the intranet - but it won't allow me to go to the web via WireGuard. What do I miss?

Here is my vanilla client config:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <reducted>
Address = 10.8.0.3/24
DNS = 1.1.1.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = <reducted>
PresharedKey = <reducted>
AllowedIPs = ::/0, 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = <reducted>:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 0
```

And My wireguard docker config:

```
docker run -d \
--name=wg-easy \
-e WG_HOST=<redacted> \
-e PASSWORD="<redacted>" \
-v /volume1/docker/wg-easy:/etc/wireguard \
-p 51820:51820/udp \
-p 51821:51821/tcp \
--cap-add=NET_ADMIN \
--cap-add=SYS_MODULE \
--sysctl="net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1" \
--sysctl="net.ipv4.ip_forward=1" \
--restart unless-stopped \
weejewel/wg-easy
```

I have a FIOS optical router at home - I've setup port forwarding and all local services (e.g. photos) are working fine

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Wireguard?

Comment: It is a docker image. I did try restarting it.